# Decidability of whether two polynomial bijections generate a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, polynomials, ds.dynamical-systems, computability-theory, homeomorphism

I am wondering about the decidability of the following question:

Given two polynomial bijections $f, g$ from the real numbers to the real numbers (with say rational coefficient just to simplify what "given" means), for example $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x^{101} + x^3 + 17$), is the subgroup of the homeomorphism group of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $f$ and $g$ a non-abelian free group?

Comment: By Tarski's theorem, the set of (codes for) such pairs $(f,g)$ is at least c.e. But I don't see how to get full decidability at the moment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is it the freely generating pairs or the non-freely generating pairs that are recursively enumerable? I would have guessed the latter but it's not clear to me what "such pairs" means in your comment. By the way, wasn't it a long-standing (but recently solved?) open problem (of Tarski?) whether $x\mapsto x+1$ and $x\mapsto x^3$ generate a free group?

Comment: @bof Yes, what I wrote was unclear: the set of non-freely-generating pairs is c.e. As to the problem you mention, I don't know, I didn't hear about it; it sounds interesting though!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not Tarski's problem but Harvey Friedman's according to an answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260045/free-group-generated-by-polynomials

Comment: @bof Ooh, neat, thanks for the link!

Comment: There is no reason to expect decidability.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That was the direction I was leaning.  My only thought for why decidability might pop in is that there could be a result along the lines of "all but the 'obviously' related pairs generate a free group"...

Comment: Consider the fact that decidability is unknown even in the case of linear fractional transformations with rational coefficients.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh I didn't know that, thank you -- that helps my intuition.